# Android Tess-Two library load data

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I am using the Tess-Two tesseract library. In most example code, the external tessdata is loaded by accessing the SD card, something like: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TesseractSample/";`. Is it possible to access this translation file from inside the resources folder instead?

Comment: You want to make it part of your pkg file?

Comment: I want to release an apk and was wondering if I could fit all the necessary files inside.

Comment: The apk is just a zip file, you can add files even after compile. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633323/how-to-add-resource-file-to-android-apk-after-compilation-and-build-of-apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not directly. You can package the training data in your app and copy it from the app's `assets` or `raw` folders onto the device external storage.